# Datatables, initComplete - select on header, not footer

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this code:

```
initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns().every(function () {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select style="width: 100%;"><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
        .on('change', function () {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    });
}
```

This is a test of what I'm doing: Here I'm testing on how to do it https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/nrzpq5g2/

What I'm trying is to append the filters of each column **on top, not in the footer**. If I set `.appendTo($(column.header()).empty())` I can have the filter on top but I lose my actual header:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/y1s6auj4/

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fd8borx9/). When you appended the select, you cleared the contents with

```
.appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
```

You just needed to avoid that action:

```
.appendTo( $(column.header()) )
```

EDIT after comment:

To avoid triggering the sorting, you can prevent the propagation of the click (like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ho4wdv9/))

```
.on( 'click' , function (evt){
     evt.stopPropagation();
 })
```

Comment: yeah, something like that. the only problem there is the sort function on the header, should be only in the title, not in the filters

Comment: I edited the answer to avoid the triggering of the sort function. The sorting symbol belongs to the header, I do not think you can work on it without going into the innards of datatable.

Comment: Prrety good. I did it with another way, but I like yous. i'll put my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was this:

```
//.appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
.appendTo( $("#table-tracking thead tr:eq(1) th").eq(column.index()).empty() )
```

But of course I need two `tr` in `thead`, and also put this option on datatable instance:

```
orderCellsTop: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I first clone the headers, and then replace them with the select ones,

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#dashboard thead tr')
    .clone(true)
    .addClass('filters')
    .appendTo('#dashboard thead');

var table = $('#dashboard').DataTable({
  "responsive": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "paging": false,
  "searching": true,
  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
  orderCellsTop: true,
  fixedHeader: true,
  initComplete: function () {
      var api = this.api();
      //For each column
          api.columns().every( function () {
          var column = this;
          var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
              //.appendTo( $(column.header()) )
              .appendTo( $(".filters th").eq(column.index()).empty() )
              .on( 'click' , function (evt){
                evt.stopPropagation();
              })
              .on( 'change', function () {
                  var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                      $(this).val()
                  );

                  column
                      .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                      .draw();
              } );

          column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
          } );
      } );
  },
      
});

});
```